# Remove Hardware Support From Qemu

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am currently experimenting with `Qemu 2.4.1` and I'd like the support for few hardware to be removed. Say like USB/Mouse/SoundCard etc.

While I was tinkering with the [source code](http://wiki.qemu.org/Download), I was able to eliminate support for a few using `default-configs/x86_64-softmmu.mak`. But, that doesn't completely solve my problem.

So well, is that the correct approach? In any case, how to selectively remove hardware support from `Qemu`?

Thanks.